# Use content_scripts on extension pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to create a communications channel from my background script to communicate with a react page that you can open via 'chrome-extension://<id>/html/index.html'

My main problem is, that chrome won't let me execute scripts on my own extension page
nor is that a valid url scheme...

Is there another way of creating a communication channel between the page and background_script?

Comment: It's a standard html page so you should simply load that script via `<script src>` tag. Inside that script you can use any `chrome` methods or the faster BroadcastChannel or even chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage().

Comment: geez Im a dumb dumb sorry... I use "browser" for cross-compatibility between firefox and chrome... (which you need to explicitly declare with chrome extensions)